# Extract single file from RAR archive with rarfile in Python

Tags: python, extract, rar

I have a RAR archive with 2 files and I want to extract only one. I found in another answer that I could use the `rarfile` package, which according to the [documentation](https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#rarfile.RarInfo) contains the `extract` function. However, when I try to run a script I get a `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]` and the following information: `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`: ... `rarfile.RarCannotExec: Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar')`.

From the information I could find, I saw it could be related with the absence of the `Unrar.exe` executable in the PATH and I tried to add it, but nothing changed. Another suggestion was to add `rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar'` to the script as a way to configure the behavior of the package, again same error.

This is my MWE, written and tested in Python 3.5.3:

```
from rarfile import RarFile

with RarFile('Test.rar') as file:
    file.extract(file.namelist()[0])
```

The file is being properly opened, since `file.namelist()` returns the archive's contents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update based on OP comments**:

I managed to unpack just one file using the following code

```
from rarfile import RarFile
RarFile.UNRAR_TOOL='C:\\full\\path\\to\\UnRARDLL.exe'

with RarFile('test.rar') as file:
    file.extract(file.namelist()[0])
```

Download [UnRARDLL.exe](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe) and provide the correct full path to `RarFile.UNRAR_TOOL`.

---

You may want to use `patool`

```
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive("Test.rar", outdir="/some/dir")
```

---

Works on `windows` and `linux`, no extra software needed.
To install use: `pip install patool`

Comment: My goal is to extract a specific file and it looks like that command extracts the whole archive. I couldn't find any documentation on that package, so I don't know about other functions available in it. Initially I was using `pyunpack`, but wanting just one file is what led me to `rarfile`.

Comment: My food arrived, I''l have to get back to you in a bit.

Comment: I did, thank you! I've updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: I followed your proposal but I got the exact same error. Are you sure you didn't do anything else? Anyway, even if it works it's not a very good solution since it implies having to at least carry that executable around. Nevertheless, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no out of the box solution to unrar without installing extra files

Comment: Well, that goes against what you proposed in the first place... The `patool` package makes it fully possible to unrar a file without any extra files. And as I mentioned, I was using pyunpack before, but also with `patool` in order to extend its support to RAR files. My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a function to unrar only specific files within that package, only the full archive.

Comment: @Alegom You must install extra files in order to extract a single file from a rar file.

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time accepting that the same procedure that can extract the whole archive, without any additional files, cannot be used to extract only specific files within that archive. But if there is no alternative, I'll have to go with that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the RAR file uses compression, you must use unrar (or something based on the unrar source code) in some way. If no compression is used, `rarfile` can do it all for you.

The solution from Pedro Lobito must work. If you get `FileNotFoundError`, I suggest you recheck your file names and paths again. In your question you say: `rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar'`, but the capitalization of `rarfile` must be `RarFile` as shown above by Pedro. Both are proper code but they have a different meaning. Also try by using the full path and don't forget the .exe.

Comment: I did recheck the names and paths. I noticed that I mentioned the "template version" of the command, but I actually used it with the proper capitalization and path, including the .exe. I really have no idea why it didn't work, but I really wanted to avoid depending on external executables. In my 4th comment in Pedro's answer, I mention that I was able to extract the whole archive with `patool`, without carrying `unrar.exe` along. If there is a way to do it to the entire archive, it shouldn't be that hard to have it for a single file. I just don't want to extract a 1 Gb file for 1 Mb.