# Unpack rar file from URL

Tags: python, rar

I didn't find any answer on how to extract specific files from RAR (not Zip) from URL.

For example, I have this URL whith quite heavy rar: http://cbr.ru/vfs/credit/forms/101-20200401.rar

What is the best way to take file from this RAR without downloading it to the disk?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, rar is still being used in 2020?

Comment: I found a similar question that uses `rarfile` to solve the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527641/extract-single-file-from-rar-archive-with-rarfile-in-python)

Comment: @Tymotex
As far as I see, rarfile doesn't have an option to open directly from URL. It opens RAR from computer directory. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried many Python Libraries, but I finally found the solution using `rarfile`

1- install `rarfile`

2- use the following:

```
import urllib
import rarfile
from io import BytesIO

resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://cbr.ru/vfs/credit/forms/101-20200401.rar')
r = rarfile.RarFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
r.namelist()
```

The output will be:

```
['032020N1.DBF', 'NAMES.DBF', '032020B1.DBF']
```

3. To open file you should use `r.open()`