# python. TypeError when extracting rar files: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, rar

I'm trying to extract a rar file using the python library rarfile.RarFile (on windows),
but it keeps giving me

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
import rarfile
rarfile=r"E:\rarFiles\CH6ED-(09_14_2021 Tue-10_10_33.99).rar"

with rarfile.RarFile(rarfile) as file:
   file.extractall(path="directory",pwd="password")
```

can anyone please help me get rid of with this error?

---

I changed my code to this

```
import rarfile

with rarfile.RarFile(r"E:\rarFiles\CH6ED-(09_14_2021 Tue-10_10_33.99).rar") as file:
   file.extractall(path="C:\Users\Joanna\Desktop",pwd="123")
```

but I gave me the same error

Comment: use a other variable name for the path as you have a library with the name `rarfile`

Comment: I changed my code, but it gave me the same error

Comment: Is that really _all_ of your code? When I tried `pip install rarfile` and just pasted in your 3 lines, I get `rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool` (seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43527756/114900 ).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `rarfile=r"E:\folder\myrarfile"` you are overwriting the name `rarfile` that was associated with the module you imported, and now is pointing to the string object `r"E:\folder\myrarfile"`. You have to name your variable that holds the path to the `.rar` file to something else. As a general advice, don't name your variables the same name used for imports.

Comment: I changed my code, but it gave me the same error. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

try

```py
rarfile.RarFile(
r"E:\rarFiles\CH6ED-(09_14_2021 Tue-10_10_33.99).rar"
).extractall(path="C:\Users\Joanna\Desktop",pwd="123")
```

Comment: still got the error:(

Comment: are you sure that path is correct? copy the file to the same folder where you run the script, and rename it to a name without the underlines and dashes.

Comment: you can also try with `PathLib`